# One capturing group in regex but javascript still returns an array

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following regex -- `/\d+([a-z]+)\d+/`

and the following test string -- `345345dffdfd34534`

example code --

```
var s = '345345dffdfd34534';
var result = s.match(/\d+([a-z]+)\d+/);
```

Why does javascript return an array instead of just the letters `dffdfd` that match the capturing group when I try to match the string with regex ?
I know it's not a big deal but is this how it is supposed to work or am I doing somethinig wrong?

EDIT: I am not asking how to access the capturing group. I know it is just a case of looking up the array. But why does JS still return two results instead of whats just part of the capturing group?

Comment: The "([a-z]+)" capturing group, groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a backreference.

Comment: [Why not read some documentation?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: @charsi the API returns an array because that's what it's defined to do. The captured groups are present in the array starting with index 1. Index 0 always holds the *entire* match.

Comment: From the docs : *An Array containing the **entire match** result **and** any parentheses-captured matched results* - pretty clear. Feel a bit dumb now.